# Will using strict equality on undefined throw an error?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm just clarifying a mismatch between the JavaScript documentation in [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) against actual experience.

[image]

I tested this myself, but it worked just fine.

```
var x;
if (typeof x === 'undefined') { 
    console.log("x is undefined, checked via typeof");
}

if(x === undefined){
    console.log("x is undefined, checked via strict equality");
}
```

Resulted into this:

```
x is undefined, checked via typeof 
x is undefined, checked via strict equality
```

I'm looking for the ReferenceError that the documentation was referring to. Tried both in Firefox and Chrome.

Please shed some light. Either the documentation is incorrect, or I'm missing something here.

**P.S.** This is what caused the confusion. In an earlier section it referred to "not defined" as a state where the variable has been declared, but was not assigned a value:

[image]

Comment: you have defined `x` in your example. the mozilla docs don't define `x`

Comment: Using any variable that isn't defined throws an error, the documentation isn't really about undefined, it's about using typeof to avoid errors with variables that aren't defined, which isn't the same as a variable that is defined, but has the value "undefined"

Comment: The problem is that "define" and "declare" caused me this confusion. If it mentioned x was not declared, instead of not defined, it would have been clearer. For me declared means x was mentioned, defined is x was assigned something.

Comment: @QuestionEverything "Declared" is whether the variable is known in an accessible scope while "Defined" refers to the variable's value. `var x;`, in this case, is declaring `x` with an initial `undefined` value. And, `ReferenceError`s only occur when a variable isn't declared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined `x` so your code does not match the documentation.

Comment: Aaah. The first section was misleading actually. It should have said: "if the variable has not been declared."

Comment: The problem is that "define" and "declare" caused me this confusion. If it mentioned x was not declared, instead of not defined, it would have been clearer. For me declared means x was declared via var, defined, means x declared and was assigned something.

Answer (score 3):

We need to distinguish between:

- declared variables whose value is `undefined` and
- variables whose names have not been ***declared***

In your case, you have the *variable declaration* `var x`, while the example does not have that declaration.

The example shows that most operations that use *undeclared* variable names will cause a reference error, but `typeof` will tolerate undeclared variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$ node
> x === undefined
ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

```
$ node
> typeof x === 'undefined'
true
```